# Writing i18n(internationalization) yml file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm writing i18n's yml file and I have a question.
I had written like this->

ja.yml

```
ja:
  users:
    show:
      index: (Japanese word inside here)
```

but I need to write word 'index' in edit page.

so I had changed like this

```
ja:
  users:
    show:
      index: (Japanese word inside here)
    edit:
      index: (Japanese word inside here)
```

word index has been overlapped, but I don't know is this right way to use i18n..

Comment: Do you want to repeat same word in different keys or what's your question?

Comment: @mechnicov yes, same word in different view. but I replaced word 'index' on top level..

Answer (score 0):

YAML supports some kind of variables like this

```yaml
ja:
  users:
    show:
      index: &index (Japanese word inside here)
    edit:
      index: *index
```